# Unable to start user managed notebook (Error: "You must specify backend ID")

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am setting up a simple user managed notebook instance via terraform/atlantis. The notebook is created fine. But the notebook does not start and keeps failing with:

```
systemd[1]: Started Google Notebooks Proxy Agent Service.
bash[1722]: 2022/12/13 10:40:03 You must specify a backend ID
systemd[1]: notebooks_proxy_agent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: notebooks_proxy_agent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

At this stage I would like to just have JupyterLab started and be able to open a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the service account is enabled. (you can find it in IAM/Service accounts).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).